# How to Combine N Number of Related Android Push Notifications

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have been reading many posts/articles/tutorials I can find about updating an active **notification**. I fear I may have a fundamental misunderstanding about how one may update an Android push notification.

So far: I can update an active notification based on its ID, and I haven't been able to get any results out of `Builder.setGroup()`

My problem: When I update an active (not dismissed) notification, *I want to be able to get the text from the previous, active notification, parse and add the new notification text and update it.*

I'm starting to think that this might not be possible without a local DB and that my approach to this problem is no good.

Is there a way to get the content of the last notification (or one with a specific ID)?

**EDIT**: It seems to me that many of the examples I have seen are grouping a number of notifications all at once rather than successively.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40uOg.png)

This is an example of what I want to do. The scenario I'm imagining is like this:

1. The owner of the device gets a notification that he/she has a new message from 'Alex Faaborg'. (See image)
2. The notification is not dismissed by the device owner
3. Another notification regarding a new message from 'Jeff Chang' comes in
4. *Get 'Alex Faarborg's' name from the first notification, and 'Jeff Chang' from the second*
5. Parse the info and display a summary of their notifications rather than have multiple notifications build up

## 4 is what I'd like to do

Comment: So this has something to do with the actual notification on the system tray? If there are multiple notifications, and you clicked on 1, you want the details of the others as well?

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm asking, I added some more detail to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I realized I could do what I need to do to combine notifications by keeping track of users' unread messages(or invites etc..) on the backend, then if there's more than one, it will send out a summary of the notifications rather than each individually. On the client, this will overwrite any previous, related notifications (kept track with a JSON field sent to GCM (and subsequently, the client) that represents the 'topic' of the notification)

For whatever reason, I thought I should handle the grouping/summarizing of notifications on the client. I think the API is the way to go.